# How to receive a non-entity class as param on POST method?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jpa

Controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/nova")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public String adicionarTemp(@RequestBody TempCaptacao temp) {
```

Param Class:

```
public class TempCaptacao{
    String dsNome;
    ...
    List<TempResponsavel> listaResponsavel;
public TempCaptacao() {

        }
```

SubParam Class:

```
public class TempResponsavel{
        Long id;
        String dsNome;
...
public TempResponsavel() {

        }
```

When Angular calls this method, passing a JSON (as below) my springs returns this error:

.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.spin.spincare.controller.MovAtendimentoCaptacaoController$TempCaptacao` (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.spin.spincare.controller.MovAtendimentoCaptacaoController$TempCaptacao` (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]]

JSON:

```
{ 
   "dsNome":"teste",
   "dsGenero":"Masculino",
   "dtNascimento":"2000-12-30T02:00:00.000Z",
   "idConvenio":16,
   "dsCep":"12321321",
   "dsEndereco":"teste",
   "dsEstado":"SC",
   "dsCidade":"",
   "dsBairro":"",
   "dsComplemento":"",
   "listaResponsavel":[ 
      { 
         "id":1,
         "dsNome":"teste",
         "nrCelular":"231321312213",
         "dsEmail":"",
         "dsGrau":"Pai"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've those empty constructor methods, but with a list inside my class, how can I pass this class as param to my POST method?

**EDIT**

Missing static definition on my TempCaptacao class.. 
Thanks!

Comment: The error sounds like you need to create paramized constructor

Comment: 1. Could you please provide formatted JSON?

2. Do you have any other constructors? Java provides empty ones by default.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm could you send me an example?

Comment: @Noskol topic updated

Comment: You really need to post the full code for all of your constructors.  It's not complaining about the list.  It's complaining that it cannot construct the parent class.  Possibly because you have nested the child class inside the parent class (?).  Impossible to see with the code you have posted.

Comment: @ArloGuthrie I was missing a static definition on my return class.. that worked properly..

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about the error and what you have posted, I think what you are doing is this:

```
public class TempCaptacao {
    // attributes etc
    public TempCaptacao() {}
    public class TempResponsavel { // inner class
        // attributes etc
        public class TempResponsavel() {}
    }
}
```

Don't do that.  Define the classes in your model separately, if for no other reasons than maintainability / readability / extendability.

I think JSON should be able to deserialize this if you remove the constructor from your inner class, but you're going to experience any number of issues doing something nonstandard like this.